# BEA Publisher Woes

Tags: bea, publisher

I'm using BEA's Publisher product with ALUI.  I want to have a simple portlet that just displays Content Items that I've published, but after playing with it for a couple of hours, I find myself stuck.

I have a Data Entry template that just takes a name and a file, and a presentation template associated with that.  But I can't figure out how to make the presentation template display a list of published content items associated with the Data Entry template.

I tried using the Tag Helper and I saw that the file properties were available, e.g. name, location, length, however I can't get the template to actually display the information.

Also, since I can't publish said presentation template (you aren't allowed to publish a presentation template associated with a data entry template), I have to make ANOTHER presentation template, and include the first one, and then make a new portlet that displays that second template.  Is this how it's supposed to work?  It seems awfully complicated for such a simple task.

I would greatly appreciate any input anyone can give.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3171395&#3171395